# Using file_get_contents with hebrew string

Tags: php, url, character-encoding, hebrew

I need help with the `file_get_contents()` function.

When I'm trying to fetch data from a url that includes some hebrew characters I'm getting an error from the host (Invalid link).

For example:

```
file_get_contents('http://domain.com/page/עברית');
```

Does not work for me.

Comment: what does the error say? Have you tried utf8_encode ?

Comment: Do a URL encode on the Hebrew characters might work

Comment: The URL is not working in browser

Comment: Your url is missing the closing quotation. Also, you should consider giving us a real url to try out with.

Answer (score 0):

Urls cannot contain UTF-8 characters. They must be url-encoded first. They may show up as UTF-8 characters in your browser, but that's just your browser making it look prettier for you.

```
When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual
data consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set [UCS],
the data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8
character encoding [STD63]; then only those octets that do not
correspond to characters in the unreserved set should be percent-
encoded.  For example, the character A would be represented as "A",
the character LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE would be represented
as "%C3%80", and the character KATAKANA LETTER A would be represented
as "%E3%82%A2".
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.5

Comment: Do you have a link to the RFC where it states that by any chance?

Comment: I added it. Hope it helps :)

Comment: You can url-encode in PHP with the built in function rawurlencode.